# Chromecast localized name?

Tags: localization, chromecast

I'm writing an app that will display the word "Chromecast" in a menu. Makes sense, right?

But my app is localized to a few different languages. Does Google have a resource where I can look up any localized trade name for Chromecast? Does it change at all between locales?

More generally, does this kind of thing exist for other brand/trade names?

Comment: CastDevice.getModelName()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromecast itself shouldn't be translated, it is a proper name and should remain the same. However, there are some other expressions and terminology that are commonly used while you are casting and we have a spreadsheet to help you with that: go to this [doc](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#cast-terminology) and look at the subsection "Cast terminology translations"